# Using 'certainly' at the end of a sentence — what is the correct punctuation and what is the construction called?

Tags: punctuation, terminology, adverbs, sentence-ends, descriptive-grammar

Consider this construction:

> Certainly, I will see you tomorrow.

The word 'certainly' constitutes an introductory phrase, and the appropriate punctuation to use is a comma. (AFAIK).

Now, consider this one:

> I will see you tomorrow, certainly.

Is this acceptable? If so, what is the name of the construction? Is a comma correct?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in British English both constructions would sound a little odd. You might expect someone to say "I will certainly see you tomorrow." Grammatically I think both are correct as you have them, with the commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities, as far as I can see. You can think of them as comment adverbs - the comment on the whole clause (like 'fortunately' or 'honestly').

The other is that they function a bit like prefaces and endings that you get in spoken English - variously called heads and tails; headers and tails. (See [this page](http://www.deltapublishing.co.uk/development/heads-and-tails).)

Whatever you call it, a comma should separate it from the rest of the clause.